# pass string argument in qsub

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, octave, qsub

I have the following shell script named dump.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#module load gcc octave
octave --eval "dumpoct($Nlay, $prefix);"
```

This script loads the octave module and then evaluates the following octave function, which simply displays the two input arguments

```
function dumpoct(arg1,arg2)
display(arg1)
display(arg2)
```

When I submit the shell script as follows, it works (passing two numbers as arguments)

```
qsub -v Nlay=10,prefix=40 dump.sh
```

However when I submit it with one number one string argument as follows:

```
qsub -v Nlay=10,prefix="qwerty" dump.sh
```

I get an error

```
error: `qwerty' undefined near line 0 column 13
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
```

I have also tried the following and I get the same errors

```
qsub -v Nlay=10,prefix='qwerty' dump.sh
qsub -v Nlay=10,prefix=qwerty dump.sh
```

Any idea how I can do that?

Thank you

Giorgos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bash interpreter issue, in that it basically removes the quotes. Try this:

```
qsub -v Nlay=10,prefix=\"qwerty\" dump.sh
```

The backslashes prevent the quotation marks from being interpreted as instructions for the bash interpreter.

Note: it may not completely solve the problem, due to bash itself being used in dump.sh. You may also need to pass the backslashes themselves... which makes it look a bit bulky, like this:

```
qsub -v Nlay=10,prefix=\\\"qwerty\\\" dump.sh
```

Which would then appear in dump.sh as \"qwerty\", which would then be interpreted by bash and be passed to octave as "qwerty". <s>Not sure if there's a more sleek solution.</s>

There's a more sleek solution, although only slightly so. It's like this:

```
qsub -v Nlay=10,prefix='\"qwerty\"' dump.sh
```

Single quote will make it pass the backslashes, but unfortunately you can't use two single quotes - it won't pass ''qwerty'' correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! The first solution works. The other two are not working becuase they actually pass as input to the function: dumpoct(10, \"qwerty\") which gives an error in octave